# Push messages for JSF and PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm developing an online chess board where you can play with others humans. At the moment users are notified about new moves by email.

Is there any elegant way to push new moves instantly to the opponents browser?

Please recommend a solution for my environment: Spring, JSF 2, PrimeFaces, Tomcat 6.

Comment: There is a4j:push for richfaces, similarily there should be prime push. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.jsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf could have something for you. You can always emulate push by subtle pulls. Primefaces component p:poll seems good for this:

```
<p:poll interval="3" 
        listener="#{counterBean.increment}" update="txt_count" />
```

Of course that is a trick / workaround and should be treated as such. It can be combined with / replaced with putting the request thread to sleep while waiting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PrimePush](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf) framework.